# Thrift API load test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, thrift

I am new into Apache Jmeter. Basically I want to load test our couple of thrift APIs but have no clue where to start with. It is in java where api takes 2 parameter and then send java object as response.

Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: You posted the same question one day earlier.  Voting down.

Comment: @CMerrill That's a reason to vote to close, not simply to vote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSR223 Sampler + Groovy (add groovy-all.jar in jmeter/lib) and look at this client example, see NonblockingClient code for an example:

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/apache-thrift-quickstart-tutorial.html

Make your groovy code call a least the following at end:

```
SampleResult.setSuccessful(true/false)
SampleResult.setResponseCode("code")
SampleResult.setResponseMessage("message")
```

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler

And of course, ensure you add the required dependencies in jmeter/lib.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have couple of more questions. I am fairly new to JMeter so please excuse me for some obvious questions. So far I have done this based on your comment:
1. Added groovy jar and my thrift client jar to apache\lib\ext folder
2. Created a JSR 223 sampler and selected language as groovy
3. Wrote a sample groovy script which ran successfully

I am lost after this. Not sure what I need to do to test my thrift API. Any help

Comment: groovy.jar and client jar must be put in jmeter/lib . Next step will be for you to analyse what custom interface are called and code the calls within the groovy script. By the way if answer is OK for you , you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to others

Comment: Could you please redirect me to some link which can help me in creating custom interface?

Comment: Finally I am able to make call to my API. Closing this thread with this answer

Answer (score 2):

JMeter isn't especially for it but it's flexible enough to support your use case.

There is an extensibility mechanism which uses BeanShell. JMeter provides BeanShell Sampler which is capable of invoking Java code, including using external jars.

Simple usage:

1. Start with empty JMeter project
2. Create a Thread Group with all defaults (you can play with number of threads, ramp-up, etc)
3. Add a BeanShell Sampler with following code:

   ```
   Thread.sleep(2000L);
   ```
4. Add View Results Tree listener
5. Save and run

You should see a green triangle (or triangles) basing on your number of threads and loops) with output like following:

```
 Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
 Sample Start: 2013-11-02 14:48:11 GMT+03:00
 Load time: 5030
 Latency: 0
 Size in bytes: 0
 Headers size in bytes: 0
 Body size in bytes: 0
 Sample Count: 1
 Error Count: 0
 Response code: 200
 Response message: OK
```

If you use any of techniques to analyze results, i.e.

- JMeter embedded listeners like Aggregate Report, Summary Report, Graph Resuls, etc.
- Storing results to CSV file and opening them with Excel or equivalent (see jmeter.properties file under /bin directory of your JMeter installation. Properties prefix is "jmeter.save.saveservice."
- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) (see Test.jmx and build.xml in /extras folder under your JMeter installation)
- [JMeter Results Analysis Plugin](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter)

You'll see your request(s) success rate, min/max/average times (something like 2 seconds I guess) and some more information (depending on your configuration).

Particular your use case assumes

1. **IMPORTANT** Placing thrift (or whatever) jars under lib/ext folder (or you won't be able to access your APIs
2. importing classes you need to test somewhere in BeanShell Sampler

   import yourpackage.YourClass;
3. Invoking methods you want to test from BeanShell Sampler
4. (optional) do some assertions on responses. i.e.

   ```
   if (yourresponse != yourexpectedresponse){
   IsSuccess=false;
   ResponseMessage= "Test Failed";
   }
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please point me to some guide to do from point 2 onwards of your comments. basically I have placed my jar uder lib\ext folder but not sure how to import classes and invoke methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have writtena CustomThriftSampler for JMeter to load test HBase through thrift service. You can get the details about it at my blog - http://1-st.blogspot.in/2013/12/load-testing-thrift-services-custom.html . Couldn't create a generalized code. Anyway its simple and starightforward java code. Anyone could try it. If time permit I shall write a generalised code and commit to github!!