# How to use Jmeter for Thrift client?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, thrift

I am working on a thrift Java Project.
I have thrift IDL , client and server. 
My Thrift server is running. 
For load and performance testing , I am using Jmeter.
I am Jmeter newbie.
Not able to understand how to use Jmeter with Thrift client. 
**On web , Not a single article have good explanation for using Jmeter with Thrift Client.


Have anyone used Jmeter with Thrift Client then please help me.**

Comment: Instead of downvoting . Please suggest what's wrong with question :P

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking for suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thrift API load test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684227/thrift-api-load-test)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm using a better search engine:

- [Load testing thrift services - Custom JMeter Sampler](http://1-st.blogspot.com/2013/12/load-testing-thrift-services-custom.html)
- [Successfully tested #thrift protocol based service with #JMeter, got 14K responses per second. Thrift API is very nice to use in TCPClient](https://twitter.com/jmeter_plugins/status/131421226139783168?lang=en)

The approach should be like:

- Add Thrift Client libraries to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- Use one of the following Test Elements:

  - [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language
  - [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler
  - [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler (this one can be the fastest and the eaiest as good projects normally have unit tests so you should be able to replay them with increased load. See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more details)